# Collect a row count per filter condition in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have written what I want to do using PL/SQL (Oracle 11g):

```
DECLARE
    cursor date_list
    IS
        WITH year_dates (active_date) AS
        (
            SELECT to_date('1997-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
            FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT active_date + 1
            FROM year_dates
            WHERE active_date < to_date('1998-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
        ) SELECT active_date
                FROM year_dates;

        l_date date_list%ROWTYPE;

        l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN date_list;

    LOOP
        FETCH date_list INTO l_date;
        EXIT WHEN date_list%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT COUNT(emplid)
        INTO l_count
        FROM ps_job a
        WHERE effdt = (SELECT max(a1.effdt) FROM ps_job a1 WHERE a1.emplid = a.emplid AND a1.effdt < l_date.active_date)
        AND effseq = (SELECT max(a1.effseq) FROM ps_job a1 WHERE a1.emplid = a.emplid AND a1.effdt = a.effdt)
        AND deptid NOT LIKE 'XX%'
        AND hr_status = 'A'
        AND company = 'ABC';

        dbms_output.put_line(l_date.active_date || ',' || l_count);

    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Basically, I want to get a rowcount for each date in an entire year and then return that as a result set.

Is there a better way to write this in pure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor seems to be okay, though you could also use `connect by level` instead of a recursive query, like this:

```
select to_date('1997-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1) as active_date
from dual
connect by
    (to_date('1997-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1))
    < to_date('1998-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Depending on how complex your data is, your loop will lead to bad performance due to the context switches for each of the loop iterations. Oracle will count the data in your table `ps_job` 365 times. Using `group by` to get all result sets at once and then output them in a loop will probably be much better.

As you did not provide the table structure of your table `ps_job`, I will provide an example using the Oracle sample table `EMP`:

```
with dates as (
    select to_date('1981-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1) as active_date
    from dual
    connect by (to_date('1981-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1)) < to_date('1982-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
)    
select dates.active_date, count(emp.empno)
from dates
left outer join emp on (dates.active_date = hiredate)
group by dates.active_date
order by dates.active_date
```

Now you could put this query into an implicit cursor loop to output your data to the console, like this:

```
begin
    for c in (
        with dates as (
            select to_date('1981-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1) as active_date
            from dual
            connect by (to_date('1981-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (level-1)) < to_date('1982-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
        )    
        select dates.active_date, count(emp.empno) lcount
        from dates
        left outer join emp on (dates.active_date = hiredate)
        group by dates.active_date
        order by dates.active_date
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(c.active_date || ',' || c.lcount);
    end loop;
end;
```

Note that if you do not need the "empty" dates, this could be made even more short, as you will not need to generate the dates first.

If you can provide the table structure and some sample data for `ps_job`, I will adapt the queries.